# Sanitize Graphql input fields using INPUT_FIELD_DEFINITION directive

Tags: graphql-java, graphql-java-tools

We use graphql-java library, and we are trying to create @trim directive for input fields, which automatically trims the input values. Can someone provide me an example how can I achieve such behavior?

All [examples](https://github.com/graphql-java-kickstart/samples/tree/master/directives/src/main/java/directives) I found are only about validation, but we need to actually mutate the field value, which I don't really see a way how to achieve it.